# ADB for multiple android devices in parallel on Windows

Tags: android, windows, adb, command-prompt

Is there a way of running ADB commands parallely on multiple connected Android devices? I need to batch install set of 5 applications on 200 devices. ADB seems to be the fastest option. However if I can do this parallely on multiple devices, then it will further save the time.

Answer (score 5):

create a `batch_install.bat` file with the following content:

```
@echo off
cls
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%a IN ('adb.exe devices') DO (
    IF "%%b" == "device" ( start /b adb.exe -s %%a install -r %1 )
)
```

Now you can run `batch_install.bat <apk_file>` to install the `apk_file` on to all connected devices.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex.P, The Badak.

In my case, Add
recursive start with input value and `serialno`
and, `set ANDROID_SERIAL=serialno` in 2nd Start

`Start cmd` can run several android devices in parallel.

And If you added `adb.exe` folder-path to System Environment path, you cannot consider cmd start address.

The following is the code:

```sh
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%1"=="" (
     FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%a IN ('adb devices') DO (
        IF "%%b" == "device" ( set devicesn=%%a )
        start %0 !devicesn!
    )
 ) else (
    set ANDROID_SERIAL=%1
    REM WRITE YOUR SCRIPT BELOW
    REM ------------------------
)
```