# Running multiple adb install on all connected devices

Tags: android, adb

So, I've been using the following [guide](https://gist.github.com/DummyCo/f3cc57a8f564baf5ba88fd16c5bae85e) to assist me with this to no avail. Has this been patched or made incompatible with ADB?

I have tried changing:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
:: INSTALL ON ALL ATTACHED DEVICES ::
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%A IN ('adb devices') DO (
    SET IS_DEV=%%B
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        SET SERIAL=%%A
        echo "adb -s !SERIAL! %ARGUMENTS%"
        call adb -s !SERIAL! %ARGUMENTS%
    )
)
```

to

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
:: INSTALL ON ALL ATTACHED DEVICES ::
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 skip=1" %%A IN ('adb devices') DO (
    SET IS_DEV=%%B
    if "!IS_DEV!" == "device" (
        SET SERIAL=%%A
        echo "adb -s install %ARGUMENTS%"
        call adb -s install %ARGUMENTS%
    )
)
```

Yet ADB continues to show the basic ADB menu of commands available and does nothing. I've done every bit of research possible to my knowledge.

What would be the arguments I need to parse?

It would suffice if I could even run multiple ADB windows to auto pick up the next device and run the install agent.apk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADB for multiple android devices in parallel on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833983/adb-for-multiple-android-devices-in-parallel-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
adb -s
```

means that you're about to specify the device name/id but it finds install so it dumps out the adb menu to say this is what I can and can't do.

So if you have only one phone connected then you can write out

```
adb install %ARGUMENTS%"
```

but if you have multiple phones you'll need to specify the phone id