# How do I set up ADB to send commands to mulitple Android devices WINDOWS

Tags: android, windows, automation, adb

I build a script for work so that installing Android phones becomes automatic. The problem I encounter is that I can't run commands if I connect 2 or more phones to my computer. Is there a way that I can run the same script on multiple Android devices?

They don't have to go simultaneously, but if it's possible I'd rather have them run simultaneously than run after each other.

I did a lot of research, but I just can't find the answer anywhere. I tried copying some peoples own made scripts without luck.

I found some post about installing apk's, but i'm looking for a way to input every command available. I did found out about this though:

```
@echo off
cls
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%a IN ('adb.exe devices') DO (
   IF "%%b" == "device" (
      start /b adb.exe -s %%a {Command}  -r %1
    )
)
```

When i put let's say {reboot} in, then multiple devices reboot. But whenever i put in shell input tap xxx xxx it doesn't work.

Comment: are you using android studio

Comment: No, i use adb version 1.0.32

Comment: see this link perhaps it may help you http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119100/how-to-connect-to-multiple-devices-at-the-same-time-using-adb

Comment: They are using mac, so the commands they use are different right? And i'm not having any issues with connecting the devices. It's the commands which trouble me. I can't run them while having more than 1 devices connected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ADB for multiple android devices in parallel on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31833983/adb-for-multiple-android-devices-in-parallel-on-windows)

Comment: @AlexP. I'm not only looking for installing apk's, i'm also looking for a way to input taps and reboot the devices. Pretty much every command should be available. I believe this post is about installing multiple apk's at once. I'm looking for more.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i finally figured it out.

```
@echo off
cls
FOR /F "tokens=1,2" %%a IN ('adb.exe devices') DO (
IF "%%b" == "device" (
  start /b adb.exe -s %%a {Command}
)
)
```

When i remove the -r %1 the input tap command works. I'm happy to see it also works when i attach one device to my computer.